# how do i remove a letter from string

Tags: php, string, character

i have string like
example

```
    $str = 'wap,net,web,andothers';
```

in my achievement i want to remove **web** from the string line so my expected result should be like  **wap,net,andothers**
i try with

```
     $str = 'wap,net,web,andother';

       $remove = 'web';  
     $str = ltrim($str, ' $remove');

   var_dump($str);
```

but could not achieve it

big thanks in advance

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, and you completely misunderstand what `ltrim()` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i explode it and then filter out the keyword `web`

```
<?php
$str = 'wap,net,web,andother';
$explode = explode(',',$str);
$result = [];

foreach($explode as $value){
    if($value !== 'web'){
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r(implode(',',$result));

?>
```

or simply, use php `str_replace`

```
$str = 'wap,net,web,andother';
$stringToRemove = 'web';

print_r(str_replace($stringToRemove,'',$str));
```

Comment: it really nice but can i be able to use variable in str_replace? Just as example
$str = 'wap,net,web';
  $remove == 'web';  
$st = str_replace('$remove','',$str);
    var_dump($st);

Comment: very wise please why my votedown an how do i go it off